# How do I setup Firebase rules NOT based on UserID alone?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I can't seem to find any documentation for this particular scenario regarding firebase read/write rules. Currently, I have my 'user' database set to only allow a logged-in user to write data and only to their 'child' in the database. This was fairly straightforward.

However, within the user 'child', there is a game ID that corresponds to the child name under the 'games' database. Here are some examples of how my data is structured in firebase:

```
(User Database Ex)
{
  "fakeuser1" : {
    "GameID" : "G071520001",
    "Name" : "Jack Sparrow",
    "email" : "fakeuser1@fakeemail.com"
  },
```

In the game database, this is how the game data is structured:

```
(Game Database Ex)
{
  "ActiveGames" : {
    "G071520001": {
          "Host" : "Jack Sparrow",
       "hostPos" : "25,45",
       "guestPos": "38,47"
    },
    "G071520200": {
          "Host" : "Jim Fake",
       "hostPos" : "25,45",
       "guestPos": "38,47"
    }
  }
```

No problem reading/writing the correct data to the correct 'active game' using JS to compare the game ID if it exists in the User profile, I'm just struggling with the *firebase rules* to set it so that a player can only write data to an active game IF they have the matching GameID within their profile.

Thanks in advance!

*edit* Both databases are 'Realtime' type databases

Comment: Please edit the question to indicate which database you're using.  There are two databases available through Firebase - Realtime Database and Firestore.  You should also show your attempt at writing rules, even if they don't work.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Unfortunately it's still not completely clear to me. Are you saying that the JSON snippets for `Users` and `ActiveGames` are both stored in a single [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database)? If to, please edit your question to show the actual JSON that you're using (as text, no screenshot). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @DougStevenson edited the question, sorry. Using Realtime database. The userID rule I used was the standard they show in the documentation, but I really don't know where to begin on the other part.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen they are two separate databases. I'll direct paste data from the .json file.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I should say two seperate real-time databases within the same Firebase project.

Comment: Yikes, are you sure you want to do that? While thinking of how to scale out your data is good, setting up separate databases per entity is not a common approach. For one thing: the security rules can only read from the current database as far as I know (I'll double check on that though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way for the security rules for one of your database instances to read data from another database instance. Allowing that would pretty much negate any performance advantage gained from having multiple instances to begin with.

You'll need to ensure that all data needed to secure access is available in the database instance. This probably means you'll need to replicate (some of) the user profile data to the database instance that user is a member of.

Comment: Thank you Frank. If I understand correctly, for example, at the time that a gameID is assigned to the user database under the user profile, the player userID (used to login) is sent to the game database under the corresponding game? Then set the rule to compare to that value?

Comment: Yeah, that sounds about right. But I'd **highly** recommend not doing that until it is needed. Creating separate database instances by entity type is an anti-pattern. You can just as easily keep both types in a single database instance, until the the number of users makes sharding it out necessary (at which point the ROI on this complex work is much better).